# In DXA site query a list of Components using the Content Query Schema

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.5, query

I want to search a list of Components in my DXA site, by two criterias, which mapped to two Keywords.

For example, I have one shop item, which has two main property:

- Category: Toys, Electronic, etc
- Info Type: Promotion, Pre-sales, etc

Based on article: [Content Lists](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-564B6EF2-C11A-4B15-8B53-7273AEB920EE&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-564B6EF2-C11A-4B15-8B53-7273AEB920EE.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-564B6EF2-C11A-4B15-8B53-7273AEB920EE), we suppose to use content query here. But content query can only support one content type, but here we have 2 dimensions. So what's the suitable solution to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

The predefined Content Query schema, associated `ContentList` View Model, `ListController` and `DefaultContentProvider.PopulateDynamicList` are currently functionally quite limited.

However, they do demonstrate a pattern you can implement yourself to do whatever kind of dynamic, query based list implementation:

- Create your own list Schema and associated View Model
- Create your own list Controller and use the CD API to perform the query
- Create your own list CT associated with your list Schema and your list Controller